# Center text over a graph in a grid cell using dash and plotly

Tags: python, css, grid, plotly-dash

I'd like to center a text over a graph in a cell of a grid table using dash and plotly. But I just cannot figure out how. Currently the graph is not centered and the text is centered in the view, but not in the cell at all.

Here's what I got so far:
[image where the text should be centered over the graph, but isn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfN5J.png)

**Dash `app.py` file:**

```
from pydoc import classname
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import plotly.express as px

external_stylesheets = [
    {
    "playground-styles.css"}
]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

data = {
    "names": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "values": [5.1, 5.7, 6.3],
}

fig_pie = px.pie(data_frame=data, names="names", values="values", title="Pie Chart")
fig_pie.update_traces(
    textinfo="none", sort=False, hovertemplate=None, hoverinfo="skip"
)

fig_pie.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig_pie.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, t=0, b=0))
fig_pie.update_layout(plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)", paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)")

app.layout = html.Table(
    [
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Div(
                    [
                        html.Div(
                            [
                                dcc.Graph(
                                        id="pie-chart-table",
                                        config={"displayModeBar": False},
                                        figure=fig_pie,
                                        style={
                                            "width":"30vmin",
                                            "height":"30vmin",
                                        },
                                ),
                            ], className = "svg-container",
                        ),
                        html.Div(
                            [
                                html.Div(
                                    [
                                        "centered over graph",
                                    ], className = "centered-text",
                                ),
                            ], className = "overlay",
                        )

                    ]
                    , className = "grid-item",
                ),
                html.Div(
                    [
                        "grid item 2",
                    ], className = "grid-item",
                ),
                html.Div(
                    [
                        "grid item 3",
                    ], className = "grid-item",
                ),

            ], className="grid-container",
        ),



    ],
    style={
        "width": "100%",
        "border-collapse": "collapse",
    },
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**`playground-styles.css` file:**

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100%; /* Set the desired width of the table */
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.svg-container {
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 30vmin;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.centered-text {
/* what do I need to put here */
}
```

Comment: It would be really helpful for you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) and put it in a [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo. Then we can see what is going on and offer a solution.

It would be best to have the HTML compiled if you could do that too.

Comment: Also, to clarify. Are you trying to center the text over the pie chart?

Comment: @davidleininger I don't believe the Stack Snippets would work for Python though, let alone Python Plotly Dash which launches and deploys a Flask web app. (It is not trivial to convert the resulting Dash app into pure html, javascript, and CSS.)

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your code like so:

#### Dash `app.py` file:

```py
from pydoc import classname

import dash
import plotly.express as px

from dash import dcc
from dash import html


external_stylesheets = [{"playground-styles.css"}]

app = dash.Dash(__name__)  # , external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

data = {
    "names": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "values": [5.1, 5.7, 6.3],
}

fig_pie = px.pie(
    data_frame=data, names="names", values="values", title="Pie Chart"
)
fig_pie.update_traces(
    textinfo="none", sort=False, hovertemplate=None, hoverinfo="skip"
)

fig_pie.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig_pie.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, t=0, b=0))
fig_pie.update_layout(
    plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)", paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
)

app.layout = html.Table(
    [
        html.Div([html.H1(["centered over grid"])]),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Div(
                    [
                        html.H2(
                            "Centered on top of graph.",
                            className="centered-text",
                        ),
                        html.Br(),
                        html.Div(
                            [
                                dcc.Graph(
                                    id="pie-chart-table",
                                    config={"displayModeBar": False},
                                    figure=fig_pie,
                                    style={
                                        "width": "30vmin",
                                        "height": "30vmin",
                                    },
                                ),
                            ],
                            className="svg-container",
                        ),
                    ],
                    className="grid-item",
                ),
                html.Div(["grid item 2",], className="grid-item",),
                html.Div(["grid item 3",], className="grid-item",),
            ],
            className="grid-container",
        ),
    ],
    style={"width": "100%", "borderCollapse": "collapse",},
    className="overlay",
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

#### `./assets/custom.css` file

(I personally would put the css in a local file called "custom.css" under a local subdirectory called "assets" (Dash is designed to specifically look for and import CSS from specifically a local directory named as such).)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex!important;
}

.svg-container {
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 30vmin;
}

.centered-text {
  position: absolute!important;
  z-index: 2!important;
}

.overlay {
  text-align: center;
}
```

which results in:
[image: Screenshot of updated dash app with text centered above grid laid out graphs and on top of first grid cell graph]

Text is centered *above* (i.e., *on top of*), the centered graph in the first grid cell. This was accomplished by setting `display: inline-grid` for the `.grid-container`, `display: flex` for the `.grid-item`s, and specifically for the text on top of the graph (`.centered-text`) additionally setting `position: absolute` and `z-index: 2` and finally also setting the `align-items` and `justify-content` parameters of `.grid-item`.

Comment: Thanks for detailed comments and explanations. Actually I did not express myself clearly. I wanted the text to be in the middle of the graph, so it actually overlays the graph.

Your hints regarding custom.css placed in a subfolder assets are greatly appreciated. In my working code I actually use it this way. For the example, I removed the folder and renamed the file.

Comment: @blackno666 Oh, I see. OK - well, I have updated my answer with one way of achieving that. Let me know if that helps or not - if so, would appreciate your accepting, and, when you can (think you need 15 reputation), upvoting the answer ✌️

Comment: @blackno666 You may want to edit your question to also include what you specify in your comment to me here. For example, instead of just saying "over", say, as you do, "overlayed on top of graph both positioned centered" (or something similar). Most people will think you mean "over" as in "above", most likely